# Entity framework serial transaction takes too much time to complete

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, transactionscope, isolation-level

I am writing a serial transaction and had some troubles.
If I only execute one thread, it executes fast, no waiting.
If I execute two or more threads, the first thread that complete takes too much time but subsequent threads are fast, why?

If I run two process concurrently of this program, each process's first thread takes too much time to complete but subsequent are fast, is this normal?

I am using sql express 2008

thanks.

```
class Program {

    int numero;

    Program(int numero)
    {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Puede presionar una tecla para salir en cualquier momento");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Program p = new Program(i + 1);
            Thread t = new Thread(p.Ejecutar);
            t.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public void Ejecutar()
    {  
        bool esPosibleProseguir = true;
        while (esPosibleProseguir)
        {
            Database1Entities cx = new Database1Entities();
            TransactionOptions opts = new TransactionOptions();
            opts.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable;
            System.Transactions.TransactionScope scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, opts);

            try
            {
                //var mayor = cx.Numeracion.First();
                //int nuevo = mayor.Numero + 1;
                cx.Connection.Open();

                int nuevo = cx.VistaNumero.First().Actual;

                var per = new Persona();
                per.Nombre = string.Format("Persona-{0}", nuevo);
                per.Ci = (1000 + nuevo).ToString();
                per.Numero = nuevo;
                cx.Persona.AddObject(per);

                //mayor.Numero = nuevo;

                cx.SaveChanges();
                scope.Complete();


                Console.WriteLine("Hilo: {0}, Crea persona: {1}", this.numero, nuevo);
                break;
            }
            catch (UpdateException ex1)
            {
                esPosibleProseguir = true;
            }
            catch (TransactionAbortedException ex2)
            {
                esPosibleProseguir = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hilo: {0}, Excepción: {1}, Mensaje: {2}", this.numero, ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
                esPosibleProseguir = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                DisponerObjeto(scope);
                DisponerObjeto(cx);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DisponerObjeto(IDisposable obj)
    {
        try
        {
            obj.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hilo: {0}, Excepción: {1}, Mensaje: {2}", this.numero, ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be because first execution of EF related code causes "model compilation" plus some other initializations which is quite time consuming operation and until this compilation is done no one else can use EF. It is just a guess but you can try to use [percompiled model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx) to validate if execution time would improve.

Comment: If I change the isolation level from serializable to read-commited the problem disappears so "model compilation" is not a cause, but I need serial transactions and the first thread is taking too much time to complete. Is this normal? Thanks for your response.